# Select all Item From Table Where Order has any Items between dates

Tags: sql-server, select

I have an `Orders` table and an `OrderItem` table. I would like to select all `OrderItems` that have been shipped between 2 dates, and select the additional `OrderItem` of a certain type that was shipped outside of the 2 dates if it's part of an `Order` that has `OrderItems` shipped between the 2 dates.

This seemed really easy when I first thought of it, but I'm having a hard time putting it into a `SQL` statement. I'm using `SQL Server`.

**EDIT:**

Yes, I am familiar with the between keyword.  What I have is an `Order`, Say `Order #10001`.  It has 2 items, a product that is shipped on `01/20/2015` and a warranty that is marked as shipped on `02/04/2015`.  So when I run my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OrderItems 
WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '01/31/2015'
```

I only get the 1 product, I want to get the warranty that is on the `Order` as well.

Hope that clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OrderItems
WHERE OrderID IN(
                  SELECT DISTINCT OrderID
                  FROM OrderItems 
                  WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '01/31/2015'
                )
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OrderItems oi1
JOIN (
       SELECT DISTINCT OrderID
       FROM OrderItems 
       WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '01/31/2015'
     ) oi2 ON oi1.OrderID = oi2.OrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with `BETWEEN` keyword?

SELECT ...
WHERE col BETWEEN  AND

If you add more information, such as sample data to your question, I can elaborate on the answer.